# How do you add CloudFront in front of API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

API Gateway (APIG), while it uses CloudFront (CF) it does not support CDN edge caching. When I configured a CF distribution to use APIG as the custom origin, I get a permission denied error.

How do I configure CF to fix this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Until API Gateway (APIG) supports edge caching via its internal use of CloudFront (CF), I have come up with a workaround.

You can indeed put CF dist in front of APIG, the trick is to force HTTPS only "Viewer Protocol Policy" AND to **NOT** forward the HOST header because APIG needs SNI.

I setup my CF "Default Cache Behavior Settings" to not forward any headers, and forced "Viewer Protocol Policy" to "HTTPS Only" and it works.  Hope this helps others.

Here is a CloudFormation resource object that has all the required configuration (Note: I use the convention `<stage>--<app name>` for StackName):

```yaml
CloudFront:  
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      Enabled: true
      IPV6Enabled: true
      HttpVersion: http2
      Comment: !Join [ '--', [!Ref 'AWS::StackName', ' Cloud Front']]
      Aliases: [!Ref CloudFrontCname]
      ViewerCertificate:
        AcmCertificateArn: !Ref AcmCertificateArn
        SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.1_2016
      Origins:
      - Id: APIGOrigin
        DomainName: !Sub
          - ${apigId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
          - { apigId: !Ref ApiGatewayLambdaProxy }
        OriginPath: !Sub
          - /${Stage}
          - { Stage: !Select [ "0", !Split [ '--', !Ref 'AWS::StackName' ] ] }
        CustomOriginConfig:
          # HTTPPort: 80
          HTTPSPort: 443
          OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
        OriginCustomHeaders:
          - HeaderName: 'Verify-From-Cf'
            HeaderValue: !Ref VerifyFromCfHeaderVal
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        AllowedMethods: ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        CachedMethods: ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
        ForwardedValues:
          Headers:
          - Access-Control-Request-Headers
          - Access-Control-Request-Method
          - Origin
          - Authorization
          # - Host APIG needs to use SNI
          QueryString: true
        TargetOriginId: APIGOrigin
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
        Compress: true
        DefaultTTL: 0
      CustomErrorResponses:
      - ErrorCachingMinTTL: 0
        ErrorCode: 400
      - ErrorCachingMinTTL: 1
        ErrorCode: 403
      - ErrorCachingMinTTL: 5
        ErrorCode: 500
DNSARecord:    
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    Comment: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
    Name: !Ref CloudFrontCname
    Type: A
    HostedZoneName: !Join ['.', [ !Select [1, !Split ['.', !Ref CloudFrontCname]], !Select [2, !Split ['.', !Ref CloudFrontCname]], '']]
    AliasTarget:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref Route53HostedZoneId
      DNSName: !GetAtt CloudFront.DomainName
DNSAAAARecord:    
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    Comment: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
    Name: !Ref CloudFrontCname
    Type: AAAA
    HostedZoneName: !Join ['.', [ !Select [1, !Split ['.', !Ref CloudFrontCname]], !Select [2, !Split ['.', !Ref CloudFrontCname]], '']]
    AliasTarget:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref Route53HostedZoneId
      DNSName: !GetAtt C
```

**Late 2018 updates**

- CloudFormation finally supports setting SSL proto ver: `MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.1_2016`
- I've baked this (and many other) best practices into an OSS project: [aws-blueprint](https://github.com/rynop/aws-blueprint)

Comment: Can you use Path Patterns with this? I have a cloudfront distribution setup with two origins: an S3 bucket for my static files, and an APIG API; but my PathPattern for the APIG doesn't trigger. I think it's because I'm not matching on a file name or type, but rather on a particular path.

Comment: API Gateway uses CloudFront behind the scenes.  If you point another CloudFront distribution to your API Gateway endpoint, CloudFront blocks the request because CloudFront has an anti-loopback check.  I.e. You can't point CloudFront at CloudFront.  I was told by an AWS engineer at AWS re:Invent 2015 that this anti-loopback check will be relaxed to allow you to point a CloudFront distribution to API Gateway.  I have not yet verified if it works yet.

Comment: I just tested and it's now working, `curl https://api.cloudprowess.com` to see it in action. I do this in order to be able to set a custom domain that uses an  SSL certificate issued by the AWS Certificate Manager, which wouldn't be available otherwise to my API Gateway. My question now is if this is going to cost me twice for CloudFront bandwidth and requests, or will the within-CloudFront costs be zero I'll ask this as a new question.

Comment: It will cost double.  Please reach out to your AWS rep asking for more CloudFront features exposed in APIG - more people that ask the better.

Comment: You can also whitelist some headers rather than disabling all. As long as the Host header doesn't pass through it seems to work fine. https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/

Comment: First of all, yes removing the host header is all you need to make this work.  I'm curious if anyone has tried this with ApiGateway set to IAM authentication.  I'm getting a signature error.  It expects a signature for host=apigateway host and not host=cloudfront host

Comment: I can't even describe how much time knowing NOT TO Forward the Host header can save people time.

Comment: Manually setting a cloud-front for an api gateway endpoint seems to generate random 500 responses (around 20%). These requests do not reach the api endpoint even if TTL is 0. Can others see this as well?

Comment: Two important points that I ran into - I had to set my Api Gateway OriginProtocolPolicy to `https-only`.  Additionally, because I was using CORS with openid connect, I also needed to whitelist my `Origin` and `Authorization` headers under Behaviors.

Comment: Can you set CF not to forward the headers from the API Console? I can't find this setting anywhere. I also tried overriding the Host field from in the origin definition, but the console did not allow it.

Comment: How did you determine the value of `DistributionConfig.Origins.Id` and `DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.TargetOriginId`? Is this something you customized or was it set for you somewhere by AWS?

Comment: Thanks! However in the `ViewerProtocolPolicy` shouldn't we put `redirect-to-https`?

Answer (score 14):

Adding to previous answers:

it's important that behavior path pattern is actually something that matches "real" path.

---

If API endpoint is `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name/my-api`

And origin domain + path is `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name`

Behavior path pattern **has to be** `my-api`, `my-api/*`, `my-api/something`, etc

---

I don't know why, but I thought that path pattern can be used as alias, for example:

https://www.example.com/random-name (path pattern `random-name`) resolves to domain + path set in origin, e.g `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name`.

That's not the case.

Comment: thank you! in my case I implemented this with an api gateway resource that matches the path pattern.

api: gateway: `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name/api/endpoint1`,

origin +path: `<id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/stage-name`,

path patten: `/api/*`,

final endpoint: `https://<id>.cloudfront.net/api/endpoint1`,

not related but I also found this answer useful for passing headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47380572/728602

Comment: Here's an implementation in AWS CDK: https://github.com/cadbox1/backend-frontend-aws-cdk/blob/master/lib/lambda-cdk-stack.ts

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks!

I had to remove originPath from my cloudfront behavior config and make sure my pathPattern matched my stage name in API gateway.

Comment: WOW. these answers were so helpful - both the answer itself and @CadellChristo's example! Now I understand that I need an `/api` resource on my API Gateway root when  I'm matching `/api/*` with the origin path value being set to the stage (eg. `/prod`).

Answer (score 4):

If API Gateway returns a 403 error with:

> Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization
>   header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires
>   'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of
>   either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.

it can also be that the origin endpoint is incorrect. "API Gateway treats all errors to non-existent paths as 403 permission denied errors rather than a 404 not found error." (see [this support thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=243041)).

I got this error and assumed I was incorrectly forwarding the Authorization header, but I had simply misconfigured the origin path.

Comment: It's very common to treat 'resource not found' as 'access denied' if the caller does not have list permissions. Otherwise you are leaking information about the names of resources, and that potentially has value to an attacker.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to reiterate here, for anyone who's following the guide from AWS premium support knowledge center,

> **How do I set up API Gateway with my own CloudFront distribution?**
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/

If you are using AWS console to set up the CloudFront distribution, the root cause is that you set **Cache Based on Selected Request Headers** to **all**.

[image]

Setting it to None or exclude the `Host` header in the Whitelist would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the launch of API Gateway regional endpoints in Nov 2017 I believe it is now optimal to use these with CloudFront Distributions on top.  Some detailed instructions for moving from Edge Optimized API's to Regional API's and setting up the CloudFront Distributions are here:

[AWS API Gateway should prevent use of TLS v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551473/aws-api-gateway-should-prevent-use-of-tls-v1/54545108#54545108)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the behavior and origin feature of cloudfront.

Have multiple origins for example S3 bucket and another api gateway.

Then based on behavior you can route to specific origin.

Like **Default(*)** behavior will point to S3.

**/api/*** behavior will point to api gateway.

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/add-cloudfront-behavior-and-origin.html code.

Much detail explanation https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/api-gateway-and-cloud-front-in-same.html