# AWS API Gateway should prevent use of TLS v1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-security-group

Refering to [AWS Cloudfront Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html), AWS API Gateway supports TLS v1.0, v1.1, v1.2.

But I want to limit the encryption protocols to TLS v1.1 and v1.2 for my Gateway API. Where do I configure this?
I do not see any cloudfront distribution for my API. Gateway resource page does not have an option to specify the security protocol.

My API is running in production for last 2 years using a custom domain.
Any idea how do I limit my API to TLS V1.1 and V1.2 protocols only in API Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone seeing this, you can now set a minimum TLS version of 1.2 for your custom domain in API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html

Answer (score 9):

I have just been working on this extensively and through a great deal of trial & error, I can document what I believe is the current optimal solution to this.  The answer from suman j was the best solution back in Oct 2017 however it does have a limitation and also AWS has evolved since then.

So what is the limitation?

If you are using Lambda with the API Gateway and delete the Custom Domain Name, then manually creating a CloudFront distribution and associating a Lambda Function requires a specific Lambda version number. That is, it does not support aliases. This is problematic with CI/CD where the version numbers can continually change.  However, the API Gateway Custom Domain Name Base Path Mappings do support aliases so it can be better to continue using these.

So how has AWS evolved?

As of November 2017, API Gateway supports creating Regional Endpoints in Custom Domain Names.  These endpoints do not create a CloudFront distribution, thus optimising the strategy of placing your own CloudFront distribution in front of them that prevents the use of TLS v1.0.

So how do I set it all up?

The steps I used to do this (via the console) are as follows. Note that you may need to change some settings to support your particular application. For the purposes of this documentation let’s say your api is named api.example.com.

1. In API Gateway, edit your Custom Domain Name, add a Regional Configuration, select your certificate and click on Save.  Note: for regional APIs, you need to use an ACM certificate from the same region as the API.    More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-migrate.html
2. Copy the Target Domain Name of the newly created Regional Endpoint.  (Eg d-abcdefg123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)
3. In Route 53 or your DNS Provider, change the mapping of your API from the Edge Optimized CloudFront target domain name to the newly created Regional Endpoint target domain name (ie d-abcdefg123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).
4. Once the DNS change has propagated, edit the Custom Domain name and delete the Edge Optimized Endpoint by clicking on the x icon.  This should then enable you to then create a new CloudFront distribution with the same CNAME of your API without AWS blocking you.
5. In API Gateway, create a new Custom Domain Name with Domain Name = regional-api.example.com, Endpoint Configuration = Regional and select the ACM Certificate.  Click on Save and then Edit and add the Base Path Mapping as per your current API and click on Save.  Copy the Target Domain Name of the newly created Regional Endpoint.  (Eg d-xyzabcd456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)
6. In Route 53 or your DNS Provider, create a new CNAME record mapping regional-api.example.com to the newly created Regional Endpoint target domain name. (Ie d-xyzabcd456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)
7. In CloudFront create a new Distribution with the following settings:

ORIGIN SETTINGS:

```
  Origin Domain Name = regional-api.example.com    

  After entering the above the following hidden fields should then be displayed:   

  Origin SSL Protocols = TLSv1.2 & TLSv1.1

  Origin Protocol Policy = HTTPS Only
```

DEFAULT CACHE BEHAVIOUR SETTINGS:
    (these values are what I needed for the app that calls the API to work properly)

```
  Viewer Protocol Policy = Redirect HTTP to HTTPS     

  Allowed HTTP Methods = GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

  Cached HTTP Methods = OPTIONS

  Cache Based on Selected Request Headers = Whitelist     

  Whitelist Headers = Authorization    

  Object Caching = Customize  

  Minimum TTL = 0

  Maximum TTL = 0

  Default TTL = 0 

  Forward Cookies = All       

  Query String Forwarding and Caching = Forward all, cache based on all     

  Smooth Streaming = No

  Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) = No     

  Compress Objects Automatically = No     

  Lambda Function Associations = None
```

DISTRIBUTION SETTINGS:

```
  Price Class = Use All Edge Locations    

  AWS WAF Web ACL = None      

  Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) = test-api.example.com      

  SSL Certificate = Custom SSL Certificate (example.com)    

  Custom SSL Client Support = Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)     

  Security Policy = TLSv1.1_2016 (recommended)
```

Supported HTTP Versions = HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0

8. While waiting for the CloudFront Distribution creation to complete (average 40 mins), in Route 53 or your DNS Provider create a new CNAME record mapping test-api.example.com to the newly created CloudFront Domain Name (eg d123abcdefg.cloudfront.net)
9. Once the Distribution creation has completed fully test your application against test-api.example.com
10. If the testing is all good then update the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) of your new CloudFront to be = api.example.com. (note - this will not make it ‘live’, the DNS change below is required for this)
11. Once the distribution update is complete (average 40 mins) then in Route 53 or your DNS Provider, update the CNAME record mapping of api.example.com to the newly created CloudFront Domain Name (ie d123abcdefg.cloudfront.net)
12. If all is working well you can now delete the Route 53 / DNS CNA  test-api.example.com record plus delete the api.example.com API Gateway Custom Domain Name.
13. For bonus points, if using Route 53 it is recommended to use A and AAAA record aliases instead of CNAME’s for the Route 53 steps above (which I have done).  This reduces cost slightly, hides the underlying CloudFront distribution somewhat and also enables IPv6 support.

I hope this helps! :-)

Comment: this answer was really helpful as we went through this process and I wanted to add one step we had to perform to get everything to work. We had to whitelist the User-Agent header, which is not in the default headers list. without that whitelisted, the user agent shows up as Cloudfront, which was causing our requests to get blocked by certain services.

Comment: I'm confused about steps 5 & 6. I have an existing custom domain in APIGW (already call test-api.example.com) and I want to prevent TLS1.0 - why are you creating a new custom domain/CNAME? I was expecting that we convert the existing custom domain name to regional, update DNS and create a new distribution to point to it. What am I missing?

Comment: thanks a lot for a great and detailed answer, works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

In order for Gateway API with additional cloud front distribution to work, we need to

1. From AWS Console, under API Gateway go to **Custom Domain Name** and delete the mapped entry.
2. Create a new cloudfront distribution with

**Cloudfront settings**

- Origin Domain Name as your Gate API endpoint https://abcdfefg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- Viewer Protocol Policy as HTTPS Only
- Origin SSL Protocols as TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1 (Uncheck TLSv1)
- Add a CNAME entry under **Alternate Domain Name** to refer to custom domain name
- and few other defaults 
  After the above changes are completed, accessing the custom domain name on https will enforce the TLS security settings as defined in **Cloudfront** distribution.

Comment: For more reference, here’s the AWS blog post on this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-cloudfront-now-lets-you-select-a-security-policy-with-minimum-tls-v1_1-1_2-and-security-ciphers-for-viewer-connections/

Comment: The problem is that deleting the custom domain name has *not* cleared the entry in the associated resources of the certificate. And I cannot create a new cloudfront with that same alternate domain name, it feels like a bug in AWS. Someone found a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

AWS has announced that this is now configurable for edge-optimised API Gateway implementations:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-api-gateway-adds-configurable-transport-layer-security-version-custom-domains/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html

Answer (score 0):

You may create API gateway distribution in your CloudFront distribution list. If your API gateway origin has HTTPS, you can specify what type of TLS protocols to be use between cloudfront and API gateway. Between viewer/client and cloudfront, you can specify the TLS protocols and suites in General section > Security Policy of CloudFront configuration. This configuration only visible if you use custom SSL with SNI. You may choose between:

1. TLSv1
2. TLSv1_2016
3. TLSv1.1_2016
4. TLSv1.2_2018

Comment: This requires provisioning a second CloudFront distribution in front of the one owned and controlled by API Gateway.

Comment: API Gateway already has a cloudfront distribution (default). However I can not see that entry in `cloud front` resource from AWS web console.

Comment: @sumanj correct.  You can't see it, access it, or modify it.  That's why the current workaround requires creating an additional CloudFront distribution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614040/cloudfront-distribution-does-not-enforce-tls-settings-for-gateway-api ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, You can enforce minimum TLS version by specifying a security policy for your custom domain. Supported security policies are TLS1.0 and TLS 1.2

- Minimum version of TLS version API Gateway security policy support is TLSv1.0
- **Recommended security policy through Custom Domain Name  is TLSv1.2**
- For greater control over TLS version, Create a CloudFront distribution in your account and use Regional API Gateway endpoint as origin.

Minimum TLS version 1.3 is only possible through Custom CloudFront distribution.

Refer : https://cloudnamaste.com/minimum-tls-version-for-api-gateway/