# AWS Cloudfront distribution does not show API Gateway distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I have a API hosted using `AWS Gateway API` in combination with a custom domain. Its been in production for at least a year.
However, when I go to `Cloudfront` resource page from `AWS web console`, I don't see any distribution entries under my same account which is used for Gateway API.

[AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) states below:

> The CloudFront distribution created by API Gateway is owned by a region-specific account affiliated with API Gateway. When tracing operations to create and update such a CloudFront distribution in CloudWatch logs, you must use the API Gateway account Id. For more information, see Log Custom Domain Name Creation in CloudTrail.

I am using the same account for both `Gateway` and `Cloudfront`. But I don't see the distribution entry in Cloudfront.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's created behind the scenes. You can't see it in your CloudWatch dashboard. That's what they mean when they say:

> "is owned by a region-specific account"

Which means the CloudFront distribution is not owned by your AWS account, so you won't see it in the list of CloudFront distributions that you own.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B . How would I update such a distribution settings to limit to TLS v1.1 and v1.2 only. My main problem is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551473/aws-api-gateway-should-prevent-use-of-tls-v1 which lead me to cloudfront distribution settings update

Comment: Did you see the comment on the answer to that question? "This requires provisioning a second CloudFront distribution in front of the one owned and controlled by API Gateway."