# When deploying my AWS API Gateway, it fails with "The domain name you provided already exists", but I can't find it anywhere

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, serverless-stack

I'm using SST, so it's CDK and CloudFormation, but ultimately, it tries to created an API Gateway that fails with this error:

```
The domain name you provided already exists. (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: c34b4b87-97be-4e5f-b0cc-1e041e49e797; Proxy: null)
```

If I change the URL from `api.example.com` to `api2.example.com` it works. I searched API Gateways and CloudFront and I can't find `api.example.com` being used in either. Also never before trying to use it for this I tried to use it, so I don't know why it would have been in use. I also waited more than 24hs in case something was *stuck*.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Check your Route53, maybe its there used for something else?

Comment: There's no record for that hostname/domain (whatever you want to call it) in that zone in route53.

Comment: I assume that these domain names need to be unique globally, is it possible it is in use in another account or in another region that you haven't checked?

Comment: I only recently added the zone to AWS. I checked a couple of other regions just in case, and nothing. CloudFront is global so need there.

Comment: @stijndepestel if you know a better way of checking, I think that's the gist of my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I saw [Matt's guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572304/740756) and removed the domain name from Api Gateway > Custom Domains. It worked after..

Answer (score 0):

Heads up; having a typo on your certificate ARN can cause this exact issue. This just happened to me. Double check your ARNs.