# Cloudfront distribution does not enforce TLS settings for Gateway API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

Follow up to [AWS API Gateway should prevent use of TLS v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551473/aws-api-gateway-should-prevent-use-of-tls-v1), I created a `Cloudfront` distribution with below config

```
Origin Domain Name as my Gate API endpoint https://abcdfefg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Viewer Protocol Policy as HTTPS Only
Origin SSL Protocols as TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1 (Unchecked TLSv1)

other defaults
```

After the distribution was deployed, when I access my Gateway API with custom domain, I still was able to make calls on TLSv1.

How do I map my custom domain to this new cloudfront distribution to enforce TLS settings?

**Update-1:**
In my java test program that calls the Gateway API using custom domain, I enabled below runtime arguments

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Output from javax.net.debug confirms TLSv1 Exchange.

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
.... many lines output
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
..
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Confirmed the TLS v1 usage using curl too.
Curl output includes:

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

Comment: How are you verifying that you are actually negotiating TLSv1?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot see my update which has debug info to confirm TLSv1 usage

Comment: What is the endpoint that is in question?

Comment: Not sure why the down vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Gateway API with additional cloud front distribution to work, we need to

1. From AWS Console, under API Gateway go to **Custom Domain Name** and delete the mapped entry.
2. Add a CNAME entry in cloud front settings. From AWS Console, follow the instructions under **Adding an Alternate Domain Name**

After the above changes are completed, accessing the custom domain name on https will enforce the TLS security settings as defined in **Cloudfront** distribution.