# whitelist Authorization header in Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, header, amazon-cloudfront, whitelist

I'm using OAuth2 with my PHP EC2 server.

From my frontend client hosted in S3, I'm making requests to my ElasticBeanstalk EC2 server (both frontend and backend are served through Cloudfront with SSL cert).

These requests are sent with required access token header as `Authorization: header ...`

It seems Cloudfront strips these headers as I'm getting error:

> error_description: "The request is missing a required parameter,
>   includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than
>   once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "access token" parameter."

I'm trying to "whitelist" this header through Cloudfront as instructed by [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web) but find it very confusing. Where in Cloudfront can I actually add the `Authorization` header to accept?

Part of the docs say:

> You can configure each cache behavior in a web distribution to do one
>   of the following:
>
> - Forward all headers to your origin

But I've already done this when I set it up:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specifically `whitelist` headers you want, otherwise choosing `None (Improves Caching)` strips headers needed:

[image]