# How to setup CloudFront with ApiGateway and S3 using AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use the AWS CDK to setup a CloudFront distribution with 2 different origins:

- S3
- ApiGateway

[Here's a diagram of the stack.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQyGY.jpg)

The problem I am having is that I can't pass the domain of the API Gateway to the CloudFront distribution properly. Here's my attempt:

```js
const api = new ag.RestApi(this, "RestApi", {
    deploy: true
});

api.root
    .addResource("api")
    .addResource("photo")
    .addResource("{id}")
    .addMethod("GET", new ag.LambdaIntegration(lambdaFunction));

const url = URL.parse(api.url);
const domainName = url.hostname as string;

const dist = new cf.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, "Distribution", {
    originConfigs: [
        {
            s3OriginSource: { s3BucketSource: bucket },
            behaviors: [{ isDefaultBehavior: true }]
        },
        {
            customOriginSource: { domainName },
            behaviors: [
                {
                    pathPattern: "/api/*"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "ApiUrl", { value: api.url });
```

If I comment out the second object in the `originConfigs` array, everything goes through, and the `ApiUrl` output prints the correct value. However, if I leave the code as in the above example, I get the following error:

```
1/2 | 12:18:13 AM | UPDATE_FAILED | AWS::CloudFront::Distribution | Distribution/CFDistribution (DistributionCFDistribution882A7313) The parameter origin name cannot be null or empty. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 1606f9b3-b3e1-11e9-81fd-bb6eb7bd9c83)
```

Answer (score 18):

I am working on the same architecture. The api.url is tokenized so url parsing will not work.

You need to build the domain name from several other properties. Also set the originPath and allowedMethods.

This originConfig worked for me:

```
{
  customOriginSource: {
    domainName: `${api.restApiId}.execute-api.${this.region}.${this.urlSuffix}`
  },
  originPath: `/${api.deploymentStage.stageName}`,
  behaviors: [{
    pathPattern: '/api/*',
    allowedMethods: cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL
  }]
}
```

Comment: That path pattern also needs to match the API Gateway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804396/728602

Comment: Thank you, @CadellChristo, it was that answer and your sample that led me to understand that I need an `/api` resource on my API Gateway root when I'm matching `/api/*` with the origin path value being set to the stage (eg. `/prod`).