# How to use API Gateway as a CloudFront origin configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

For context, I'm building a small application that uses Django and Vue.js. I want to do the following:

1. send Django requests (`/api/` and `/admin/`) to API Gateway where they are served in AWS Lambda functions
2. serve requests to `/media/` and `/assets/` with an S3 Origin in CloudFront
3. serve all other requests with an S3 website where the static assets for my Vue.js application are stored

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this using the same domain/subdomain for each of the three CloudFront origin configurations.

I know how to setup a custom domain name for API Gateway, for example `api.mysite.com`. If I have the CloudFront distribution pointing to it with a Route53 A record for `mysite.com`, I was thinking that I could setup a custom origin configuration that points to `api.mysite.com` on path patterns of `/api/` and `/admin/`. Trying this resulted in a 502 error on CloudFront when I tried accessing `mysite.com/api/health-check/`, but I get a healthy health check when I access `api.mysite.com/api/health-check/` (the API Gateway custom domain name).

I think I'm having an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), because I'm not sure that this is advised or even possible. Should I just use a different subdomain for API Gateway and setup CORS so my Vue application can make requests to the Django API? Or would it be possible to use one CloudFront distribution for an S3 website, S3 Origin and API Gateway?

I'm using CDK to define all of my infrastructure. I have previously used ALB on the same domain name as the S3 website and can make requests to the API on the same domain name without needing CORS, but I'm new to API Gateway and not sure how their custom domain names work yet. Also, the fact that `stage` is appended to the URL for the API Gateway domain is confusing for me, I'm not sure if or how this would play into my solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Here is a nice tutorial written by AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/

Comment: Could you post the CDK code in order to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi again, @jellycsc! Here's a link to the CDK code for the project I'm working with: https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/djambda/-/tree/master/awscdk/awscdk. I'll have a look at the link you shared, thanks!

Comment: I don't seem to have access to your code. I don't have a gitlab account.

Comment: Sorry about that, just made it public @jellycsc

Comment: No problem. I can see it now.

Comment: You should set the `origin_protocol_policy` to `HTTPS_ONLY` for api gateway origin. https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/djambda/-/blob/master/awscdk/awscdk/cloudfront.py#L35

Comment: Also, you should exclude `Host` header [here](https://gitlab.com/briancaffey/djambda/-/blob/master/awscdk/awscdk/cloudfront.py#L42). Please see the following for detailed reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32825413/10692493

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks again for your help @jellycsc . I'll mark this question as a duplicate of the question you posted above.

Comment: yay! you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple origins within the same CloudFront distribution to get around this problem.

You would have the following setup:

- Default origin - Route to your S3 Website
- Origin for '/api/*' - Route to API Gateway
- Origin for '/admin/*' - Route to API Gateway
- Origin for '/media/*' - Route to S3 Origin
- Origin for '/assets/*' - Route to S3 Origin

Additional origins after the default support path based routing (although an origin can only support a single path).

If this is all setup then you can assign your hostname to the single CloudFront distribution.

Here is more information on [setting up multiple origins](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/).

Comment: Thanks Chris, where you have `Route to API Gateway`, does that refer to the `https://abc123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` domain name? Should I not be setting up a separate custom domain name with Route53?

Comment: It can go to the execute-api domain directly, ensure that the domain type for the custom domain is regional though

Comment: OK, I'm going to try that now.

Comment: OK great, let me know if you need further help :)